# Python BigQuery Client Caching does not work

Tags: python, google-bigquery

It seems like the caching for the Python bigquery library does not work. The example below always prints `None`. How can I fix this issue?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
query = """
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1)
"""
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_query_cache = True
results = bq_client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
print(results.cache_hit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you gotta do something with the results object first. For example `results.to_dataframe()`.

Thx to VictorGGI and William Funks:
"cache_hit" will return "None if job is not yet complete" ([cache_hit](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html?highlight=cache_hit#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.cache_hit)). You would need to run "done" ([done](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.done)) to verify job is completed, or any other method which verified this

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use `to_dataframe`. This worked because this method blocks the job execution until it reaches `done` state and reloads the config back to the job query with the updated information of `True` in `cache_hit` property.

Comment: "cache_hit" will return "None if job is not yet complete" (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html?highlight=cache_hit#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.cache_hit). You would need to run "done" (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.done) to verify job is completed, or any other method which verified this, as stated by @WillianFuks . Consider adding this additional info to your answer and accepting it.